# What determines when I can revive an ally?

Tags: xenoblade-chronicles-x

A few times now when over a dead friend I have gotten the "Help Me" prompt. Pressing A then restores some of their help and they get back in the fight. There does not seem to be any rhyme or reason to why and how it shows up. So what determines if i can actually revive somebody or not?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You should be able to revive someone if you have 3000 TP. You party members can do the same thing, but they usually use an Art, blowing their chance to revive you. You can send a battle command to your party to build the tension, which will help but doesn't by any means guarantee they'll save the TP required to revive you.

Comment: To clarify a little: Your party wont use any TP at all when you tell them to build tension. The problem will be if your teammates will actually build up the 3000 by the time you need it. If they have 0 when you go down, it's unlikely they will build 3000 in the 30 seconds you have until you are very late game with builds based around building a lot of TP.

Answer (score 2):

You need 3000 TP to revive a fallen ally.